# Pass variable from ViewPager to Clicklistener

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

How can I get the actual position of a `ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener()` to a `OnClickListener`:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    btnDL.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // I need the "int posistion" here

        } 
    });
}
```

So this is the `OnPageChangeListener`:

```
private void setCurrentItem(int position) {
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(position, false);
    displayMetaInfo(selectedPosition);
}

//  page change listener
ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener viewPagerPageChangeListener = new  
ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        displayMetaInfo(position);

        // I need this position in my OnClickListener
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: `viewPager.getCurrentItem()` returns you the current position

Comment: have u tried `viewPager.getCurrentItem()`

Comment: Are you trying to pass the position from PagerAdapter to a fragment/ activity?

Comment: That was the expression I was looking for! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
@Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup
   container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    btnDL.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int pos = viewPager.getCurrentItem();
    } });
```